# How to improve bit reading process in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, fread

I need to read a binary file and the Matlab coding is:

```
a = uint8(fread(fid,'ubit1')');
```

This is inefficient so I added a line below:

```
a = uint16(swapbytes(a));
```

and also tried this:

```
a = double(uint8(fread(fid,'ubit1')'));
```

But both of them do not help. Any other method to improve the bit reading process in Matlab?

Comment: Improve in what way? Make it faster? Make it use less memory? What is the problem? Please be specific!!!

Comment: MATLAB doesn't have a single bit type but you can store a one or zero in separate values. Is that what you need? To run fast you need to read in the file into an array then parse the bits after that.

Answer (score 0):

To read into an array use this:

```
a=fread(fd, Inf, 'ubit1=>uint8');
```

This creates a column vector of unsigned bytes with a bit stored in each array element. Unfortunately, MATLAB is pretty slow at doing bit manipulation.

Then just access them `a(1)`, `a(2), etc

Comment: It shows error: **Index exceeds the number of array elements.** As my project is a decoder where each block contains different number of bit. 
And I need to read the input file bit by bit in order to execute the function in each block. Eg. the first line of my code is `if( y(b:b+14) == blockA)` which causes the error.

Comment: @Ralph, You need to provide enough code that you are trying to process the bits read for us to understand what will help.

Comment: Hi @doug, I am referring to the coding [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27303-complete-implementation-of-a-mp3-decoder) It takes a long time to decode a file. So I am thinking how to improve the file reading process.

Comment: @Ralph. Adding a defined precision `uint8`  as the last argument should produce the fastest array reading of individual bits. It still uses 8 times more memory than the file being read but Matlab is going to be slow in any case at this. Otherwise you are reading them into a double array and that's another 8 times larger. Really slow.

Comment: thanks @doug. But the coding provided `a = fread(fid, Inf, 'ubit1', 'uint8');` shows error: **Error using fread. Invalid machine format.**

Comment: @Ralph  You're right. I had the wrong syntax. Will edit the answer. I normally just read into `uint8` arrays with the full 8 bits in each byte. That uses a lot less memory and is faster but doesn't give you the bit, by bit needed to easily use the code you linked to

Comment: Hi @doug, is it possible to implement by using `GPUArray`?

Comment: No, that would be slower. This is really more of an OS/filesystem issue. However, you might be able to speed things up using MEX and coding the IO in C++.

Comment: Hi @doug, how about increase the thread in Matlab? [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/release-notes.html#bvczl_g-1)  **Multithreaded Workers: Use multiple computational threads on your MATLAB workers**

Comment: Matlab has been highly optimized to take advantage of multithreading. However, reading large files into a Matlab vector rarely benefits from multithreading due to limitations of I/O hardware. The fastest way to read large files is reading them one large block at a time straight into a byte array. Since you want each int8 element sent back to Matlab to contain 1 bit of data a second pass is needed. That part could likely be speeded up significantly with multithreading in a C++ MEX dll.